# Downloading data from MapServer (MS4W)

Tags: mapserver, parcel, ms4w

Does anyone knows how to pull out the data from mapserver? I have installed it on my PC, but have no idea how to use it and pull out the data from one link.
Link : [http://www.catastrochaco.gov.ar/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?http://www.catastrochaco.gov.ar/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\mapa\assets\mapfiles\catastro-mapa-chaco.map&LAYERS=capa_parcelas_todas&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=5425782.1760478,7046795.5756545,5430452.9513034,7050951.2956327&WIDTH=662&HEIGHT=589](http://www.catastrochaco.gov.ar/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?http://www.catastrochaco.gov.ar/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:%5Cms4w%5CApache%5Chtdocs%5Cmapa%5Cassets%5Cmapfiles%5Ccatastro-mapa-chaco.map&LAYERS=capa_parcelas_todas&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=5425782.1760478,7046795.5756545,5430452.9513034,7050951.2956327&WIDTH=662&HEIGHT=589)

And is it possible?

Comment: http://www.catastrochaco.gov.ar/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\mapa\assets\mapfiles\catastro-mapa-chaco.map&LAYERS=capa_parcelas_todas&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=5425782.1760478,7046795.5756545,5430452.9513034,7050951.2956327&WIDTH=662&HEIGHT=589 seems to be working fine, You don't need mapserver locally just a client like QGIS